# I have done all the things but I am not able to solve this problem

Tags: javascript

[image: JS Code]

This is my JavaScript code

[image: Console Error]

This is what console shows.

[image: HTML]

This is my HTML

Comment: Please post the code, instead of the image of your code.

Comment: Also, in your HTML code **``ID``** for **decrement counter** `button` has extra space.  `id="decrement "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the future I would suggest to post your code as text and not as an image. Next to that a bit of explenation could be usefull and kind. Also this is Javascript code, not java code.

Here you have a working version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/r4anp9xq/1/

```
<h2>Counter <span id="counter">0</span></h2>

<button id="increment">Increment counter</button>
<button id="decrement">Decrement counter</button>
```

The problem was with the id in your HTML. You included a whitespace so your javascript code could not find the correct one.

Comment: thanks for the solution man really appreciate your effort. I was not expecting that I would get answer of my questions. I was thinking that it would probably take few weeks than someone will give the answer. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file at line 15, delete the white space you left in the id

from `id="decrement "` to `id="decrement"`

id 's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID value. ([MDN ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id))

Comment: thanks for the solution man really appreciate your effort. I was not expecting that I would get answer of my questions. I was thinking that it would probably take few weeks than someone will give the answer. By the way thanks.